# The passed data is ModelObject::ActiveRecord_Relation, not String Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to obtain the id from a table using a where clause, but the value return as an ActiveRecord_Relation.

```
def generate_qrcode
    idBuscado = get_id_beneficio(3) #the 3 it's just for testing values
    qrcode = make_qrcode(idBuscado)
    send_data qrcode.to_s, type: 'image/png', disposition: 'inline'
  end


private def get_id_beneficio(idBuscado)
    itemlist = Beneficio.select('Id_beneficio', :conditions => ['id_beneficio = ?', "%#{idBuscado}%"]).limit(1)
  end

private def make_qrcode(cadena = 0)
    qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new(cadena)
    image = qrcode.as_png(
        resize_gte_to: false,
        resize_exactly_to: false,
        fill: 'white',
        color: 'red',
        size: 300,
        border_modules: 3,
        module_px_size: 4,
        file: nil # path to write
        )
    image.resize(150, 150)
  end
```

and the error that show... [image: Error]

I need to now how to get the value named **Id_beneficio** and return it as a Integer. Any advice? :(

[[UPDATE]]

Now with the new suggestion the values that i obtain it's

[image: new error]

however in the console show's that the sql command execute smoothly

```
Beneficio Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  id_beneficio FROM `beneficios` WHERE (id_beneficio = '3') ORDER BY `beneficios`.`Id_beneficio` ASC LIMIT 1

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)



RQRCode::QRCodeArgumentError (The passed data is NilClass, not String):
```

and the new method to obtain the values

```
private def get_id_beneficio(idBuscado)
    Beneficio.select('id_beneficio')
          .where('id_beneficio = ?', "#{idBuscado}")
          .limit(1)
          .first
          .id
  end
```

Comment: Does Beneficio has an id attribute?

Comment: yeah it does, the only value that i need it's the id, but just return as an ActiveRecord_Relation

Comment: `itemlist` will be a record. You need to access the id  `make_qrcode(idBuscado.id)`

Comment: the view return another error, this time: undefined method `id' for #<Beneficio::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x7189170> Did you mean? ids

Comment: and if i change the value id to "ids" i get:    The passed data is Array, not String

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could specify to get the first element in your query result. As you're using `where` it'll give you an ActiveRecordRelationship, despite using `find`.

You have many ways to make it work, as creating `idBuscado` as the id of the result when passing 3 to `get_id_beneficio`, like:

```
idBuscado = get_id_beneficio(3).id
```

Or access the id in the `qrcode` variable:

```
qrcode = make_qrcode(idBuscado.id)
```

Or configuring your get_id_beneficio private method to get the id from the first record, like:

private

```
def get_id_beneficio(idBuscado)
  Beneficio.select(:Id_beneficio)
          .where('id_beneficio = ?', "%#{idBuscado}%")
          .limit(1)
          .first
          .id
end
```

Any of both first actions need you access the first record, otherwise you're trying to get the id from an AR Relationship, not a single record.

Note you don't need to add private to all of your methods you want to make private, just put the reserved word and each declared method down this will be a private one.

Comment: the value change to nill

Comment: Can you corroborate the value isn't nil? In your rails console? checking the query in your rails server?

Comment: Try to debug the value `idBuscado` before calling the `make_qrcode` method.

Comment: Welp, return nil. The thing it's that the query that rails generate run perfectly in mysql. but for some reason returns nil

Comment: i made some changes to the method, now i retrieve the value that it's 3 from the database, however the error now show The passed data is Fixnum, not String

Answer (score 0):

Well result that the method i need was

```
private def get_id_beneficio(idBuscado)
Beneficio.where(id_beneficio: idBuscado).pluck(:id_beneficio).first
end
```

and then convert the value that i obtain to string with idNumero.to_s